# Enable anonymous read only access to users in Argo-workflows similar to Argocd

Tags: argo-workflows

I have installed Argo workflow using Helm chart at https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/tree/master/charts/argo-workflows
However when accessing the UI (ingress enabled) I am greeted with the login screen with options to login with SSO or 'argo auth token'.
Is it possible to enable anonymous read only access to users similar to Argocd?

Answer (score 2):

Find the name of the server pod

```
lausser@roosevelt:~/git/argo-workflows$ kubectl -n argo get pods
NAME                                                         READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
arschgo-argo-workflows-workflow-controller-69dcddf54-jhgfx   1/1     Running    0          42m
svclb-arschgo-argo-workflows-server-z4vhh                    1/1     Running    0          42m
arschgo-argo-workflows-server-6777499bc-2brcc                1/1     Running    0          42m
base-template-nzfs8                                          1/2     NotReady   0          19m
```

and then

```
kubectl -n argo exec pod/arschgo-argo-workflows-server-6777499bc-2brcc -- argo auth token
```

and it will output the token.
(my namespace is "argo")

Answer (score 2):

with one command

```
kubectl -n argo exec $(kubectl get pod -n argo -l 'app=argo-server' -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') -- argo auth token
```